# How can I iterate thought JLabel objects to add a icon to a specific one

Tags: java

so I'm bit new to this. So I have a bunch of JLabels (javax.swing.JLabel) and want to be able to loop through them adding a icon to a specific one that could change each time.

```
private void myMethod(JLabel l){
        int x = 6;
        for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
            if(x == 6){
                l.setIcon(set icon to something nice);
            break;
            }else{
                l++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I basically want to do this, how would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: You should hold your `JLabel`s in some sort of collection, for example in an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Then access the one you need, retrieving it from this collection. What is unclear to me when reading your question is the criteria which label to select. You should elaborate on that.

Comment: Not sure what you want, but well, you should start by keeping your label objects in a list for example. That you can then iterate and work with.

Answer (score 0):

Okay yeah that was a very easy solution. Thanks GhostCat and maloomesiter! For some reason I was way overthinking that. Just putting the objects in an arraylist and doing it that way was very straightforward once you guys suggested it. Thanks!